# Using ui-router and parameters

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, get, angular-ui-router

I have a page called `products`, there is a list of products that I list out using ng-repeat. For each product, they each of a `<a>` tag for links. I want each of the links to send the user to `products/item?productid=xxx` where xxx stands for each particular item's id.

Using ui-router, how do I go about using the `<a>` to send a GET parameter to `products/item` and how do I use ui-router to detect the GET parameter and load the item's data (e.g. name, description) into the item's page controller.

I've read https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing so if I set

```
$stateProvider
.state('products.item', {
    url: "/products/:productid",
    templateUrl: 'products.item.html',
    controller: function ($stateParams) {
        // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
        expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});
    }
})
```

what do I set the line `expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: "42"});` to?

I was doing this with PHP. In PHP I had to change the `<a>` to `<button>` and trigger a form submit. Then using $_GET, I would call another PHP script with the parameter and parse the JSON response. However, I wanted to change it into a single page so there would be no full page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong property name. It needs to match the value you define in the `url` property on your state definition object. So if you have

```
 url: "/products/:productid",
```

defined on your state then if you go to 'products/42', you should be able to access that value on the $stateParams with..

```
expect($stateParams).toBe({productid: "42"});
```

Comment: If I have multiple productid like 1-100, do I need to make a `expect($stateParams).toBe({productid: "42"});` for each item from 1-100?

Comment: And how do I set a default for it just so that when a user types `http://www.blahblah.com/products/item` without a GET parameter it redirects them elsewhere?

Comment: You don't "need" to put the expect() call anywhere. That's just there to demonstrate that you have access to that information if you need it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I think it gets a bit more involved. There is some discussion on that here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/108